# i can't record audio files on chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, audio, ionic-framework

I have a problem. I made a website using ionic and I need to record audio with the microphone.

in version 39 of Chrome it works perfectly and me to allow notice appears in microphone.

in chrome in higher versions of the notice does not appear, therefore I can not use the microphone.

in firefox the nofiticacion appears and click allow , it appears to allow the use of the microphone but 3 seconds after the icon disappears and does not allow me to record audio.

There are some plugin or something that I can put you to my website to walk regardless of the browser because users can not meddle with things manually in their browsers.

Will be security reasons, or will not be a https connection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in **iONIC**, but this solution is works for me in **Website**

I just tried for **Voice search for Website**. I Found that, voice search script works with only **`HTTPS`**. In local, Browser doesn't let me record audio, but while I upload this file in my **`HTTPS`** protocol website, It works fine.